# How do I use AWS to update my iOS App without an official app update?

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, amazon-web-services, uiwebview

So I have an app that is pretty simple. It has data stored in .htm files which can either be displayed in a UIWebView or parsed through and return a string of the results(the app does both). The data changes weekly, and obviously it takes longer than that just to review an update submission. I want the user to be able to click a button and check for updates on a server and then download/replace the .htm files as needed. The app can take it from there. What service through Amazon Web Services is the best to check for new files and download them? If you think there is an easier service than AWS than I'm definitely open to other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your files in S3. Set up your app so it downloads the file from S3, then compare it with the one you've got locally (you could hash them both and compare the hashes).

If it's changed then you can use the new one.

Comment: Thanks! One other thing: If I download the file from S3, wont there be an error because a file with that name already exists?

Comment: Get the file from S3, store it in memory (as a variable), compute a hash of it, then read in the current file and hash it, then compare the hashes. If they are equal then the files are the same. Then save the file and overwrite the old one. Alternatively, don't bother with the hashes. Use some other method to tell if the file is new (have the date in the title or something).

Comment: When I say download it, you don't have to save it immediately. You'll probably end up with an NSFile object which you can play around with before saving.

Comment: Last thing(for sure this time): How do I get a file from S3? If its too complicated for a comment feel free to just tell me to google it haha

Comment: Yup, that's one you're gonna have to find out for yourself. Have a look at https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking though, haven't personally used it for downloading files, but it seems like a pretty versatile library.